# Sentiment score difference between first and last incoming post

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe where each row has a unique conversation ID. Each conversation is made of unique posts which can be either incoming or response post (but not both) (customers post incoming posts and agents post responses). Each post has a sentiment score.

I want to calculate the change in sentiment by measuring the difference between first incoming post and last incoming post. Below is the sample dataframe.

```
# A tibble: 11 x 11
   conversationID postID postType conversationOrd… incomingOrder responseOrder createdDate closedDate convResponseHan…    tar sentence_score
            <dbl>  <dbl> <chr>               <dbl>         <dbl>         <dbl> <chr>       <chr>                 <dbl>  <dbl>          <dbl>
 1       25455628 4.74e7 Incomin…                2             2            NA 10/07/2019… 10/07/201…            NA     NA             0    
 2       25455725 4.74e7 Incomin…                1             1            NA 10/07/2019… 10/10/201…            NA     NA             0    
 3       25455725 4.74e7 Incomin…                2             2            NA 10/07/2019… 10/10/201…            NA     NA             0    
 4       25455725 4.74e7 Incomin…                3             3            NA 10/07/2019… 10/10/201…            NA     NA             0    
 5       25455725 4.18e6 Response                4            NA             1 10/08/2019… 10/10/201…            23.4  748.            0.184
 6       25456349 4.74e7 Incomin…                1             1            NA 10/07/2019… 10/08/201…            NA     NA             0.3  
 7       25456349 4.18e6 Response                2            NA             1 10/07/2019… 10/08/201…             3.17   5.15          0.440
 8       25456349 4.74e7 Incomin…                3             2            NA 10/07/2019… 10/08/201…            NA     NA             0.113
 9       25456349 4.18e6 Response                4            NA             2 10/07/2019… 10/08/201…             0.67   3.03          0.786
10       25456349 4.74e7 Incomin…                5             3            NA 10/07/2019… 10/08/201…            NA     NA             0.214
11       25456349 4.18e6 Response                6            NA             3 10/07/2019… 10/08/201…             1.58   2.43          0.251
```

In ideal scenario, I would want another column called sentimentConversion which indicated whether the conversation (from customer's perspective) changes Positive to Negative, Negative to Positive, or remains same.

Here's the `dput()` output.

```
structure(list(conversationID = c(25455628, 25455725, 25455725, 
25455725, 25455725, 25456349, 25456349, 25456349, 25456349, 25456349, 
25456349), postID = c(47371258, 47371485, 47371486, 47373371, 
4184259, 47373084, 4181224, 47374183, 4181324, 47375140, 4181430
), postType = c("Incoming Post", "Incoming Post", "Incoming Post", 
"Incoming Post", "Response", "Incoming Post", "Response", "Incoming Post", 
"Response", "Incoming Post", "Response"), conversationOrder = c(2, 
1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), incomingOrder = c(2, 1, 2, 3, 
NA, 1, NA, 2, NA, 3, NA), responseOrder = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, 
NA, 1, NA, 2, NA, 3), createdDate = c("10/07/2019 08:45:14 PM -0400", 
"10/07/2019 08:48:25 PM -0400", "10/07/2019 08:48:25 PM -0400", 
"10/07/2019 09:20:26 PM -0400", "10/08/2019 09:16:24 AM -0400", 
"10/07/2019 09:15:45 PM -0400", "10/07/2019 09:20:52 PM -0400", 
"10/07/2019 09:35:47 PM -0400", "10/07/2019 09:38:47 PM -0400", 
"10/07/2019 09:55:49 PM -0400", "10/07/2019 09:58:13 PM -0400"
), closedDate = c("10/07/2019 08:49:36 PM -0400", "10/10/2019 09:16:44 AM -0400", 
"10/10/2019 09:16:44 AM -0400", "10/10/2019 09:16:44 AM -0400", 
"10/10/2019 09:16:44 AM -0400", "10/08/2019 09:06:33 PM -0400", 
"10/08/2019 09:06:33 PM -0400", "10/08/2019 09:06:33 PM -0400", 
"10/08/2019 09:06:33 PM -0400", "10/08/2019 09:06:33 PM -0400", 
"10/08/2019 09:06:33 PM -0400"), convResponseHandleTime = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, 23.42, NA, 3.17, NA, 0.67, NA, 1.58), tar = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, 748.28, NA, 5.15, NA, 3.03, NA, 2.43), sentence_score = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0.183532587096449, 0.3, 0.439929079364222, 0.1125, 0.785712147332011, 
0.21354963890361, 0.251196909045889)), row.names = c(NA, -11L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Would you be able to provide sample data using `dput()`? And just to clarify - the first and last incoming post is based on date/time in `createdDate`? Or is it `conversationOrder` or other? Is sentiment the `sentence_score`?

Comment: You got it right, `sentence_score` is the sentiment. You can use either `createdDate` or `conversationOrder` for post orders. This is my first time printing the output so hope it's the right way :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are only looking at `Incoming Post` to determine change in sentiment scores, you can filter by this variable.

I would arrange by `converationOrder` to make sure they are in order, before selecting the first and last within each group defined by `conversationID`.

The `sentimentChange` will subtract the last from the first. Then it will be coded for your `sentimentChange` based on being greater or less than zero (or same).

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  filter(postType == "Incoming Post") %>%
  arrange(conversationID, conversationOrder) %>%
  group_by(conversationID) %>%
  summarise(sentimentChange = last(sentence_score) - first(sentence_score)) %>%
  mutate(sentimentConversion = case_when(
    sentimentChange < 0 ~ "Down",
    sentimentChange > 0 ~ "Up",
    sentimentChange == 0 ~ "Same"))
```

**Output**

```
# A tibble: 3 x 3
  conversationID sentimentChange sentimentConversion
           <dbl>           <dbl> <chr>              
1       25455628          0      Same               
2       25455725          0      Same               
3       25456349         -0.0865 Down
```

Comment: This is amazing. This does solve my original question. 
I'm actually trying to pick up conversations where customer came in with negative sentiment but we were able to transform that conversation into a positive one. In the current dataset there's too much noise plus `sentimentr` is marking lot of neutral conversation as negative. 

Is there a better library or a better way to do this? I know this a very open-ended question but just checking...

Comment: Glad this was helpful. I am not an expert by any means in sentiment analysis, but do understand there are other packages out there available for this. The issue may reflect more about the "science" of sentiment analysis and its ability to handle such conversational data. You might want to consider this is a different question on stackoverflow (or on Stack Exchange in Data Science). Good luck!